# How can I use speech recognition with C# on Windows XP? + do I need to train every pc that runs the app?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, speech-recognition

I am making a robot that responds to few voice commands. I am using Windows XP and C# to achieve that. My only problem is that I don't know how to use speech recognition with C#.

I've been searching Google and MSDN, but I did not find any beginner friendly tutorial yet..

Any suggestions??

Also, I know -from my experience with windows' speech recognition in M$ word- that I need to train the computer before starting the speech recognition application. This may cause a big problem for me because I may need to present my robot using different computers/or/different people may be the presenters.
So is there any way to make a predefined list of words that any user can say to the application without having to train it first???

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to train anything that uses pattern recognition to respond to things. In Philadelphia, they pronounce "water" as "wudder". How could an algorithm figure that out? A predefined list would require you to have a working knowledge of every accent in the target sales countries.

Answer (score 0):

SAPI 5.4 in Windows 7 does a very good job of recognizing limited command & control grammars without training.

If you keep your command set (grammar) small (say, no more than 10-15 commands), you should be able to get good results.

Dictation or a large command set requires training; there's just too much uncertainty.